# Can't install my own Xamarin application on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.android

We have Xamarin app in our company, that used to work in the past, where I wasn't working here.
Now when I try to install an .apk it throws "App not installed as package appears to be invalid".
I thought that it could be a problem because of target version of Android is 12 and I have Samsung A53 with Android version 13. But then I tried to install it on another phone (Samsung A31) which can handle max Android 12, so it should be OK. No, it's not, now it throws "Can't process package".

VS 2019, all kind of architectures is checked in android project settings.
Btw, works perfect on Android Emulator, Pixel 2 Android 9 with x86 architecture (was installed when I came here).

Tried to figure it out by "classic" methods and found strange post where guy said his exact same problem was made by some kind of ListView issues.
Can it even possibly be true and what can I do to handle that?

Comment: "App not installed as package appears to be invalid" usually happens when you already have an app with the same package name on the phone. Given that this is an old version of the app, and you potentially have a new version, prod version, or any other app from the company that might be using the same package name, that might be the issue. I'd say try deleting that/ those apps through the system application manager on the phone and try again. Hope that it's as simple as that.